# PHP variable not concatenating correctly

Tags: php

My `$app_id` variable is not concatenating correctly in the `$URL` variable.

```
   $result = $_GET;

    $app_id = $result["appid"];

    $KeyWord = test_input($return["keyword"]);

    $URL ="http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?siteid=0&SECURITY-APPNAME=. $app_id . &OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&keywords=";

$URL=$URL.$KeyWord.$app_id."&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=".$NumPerPage."&paginationInput.pageNumber=".$pageNumber."&sortOrder=".$sortOrder.$condition.$minPrice.$maxPrice.$buyingFormat.$seller.$FreeShippingOnly.$ExpeditedShippingType.$MaxHandlingTime.$SellerInfo.$PictureURLSuperSize.$StoreInfo;//
```

I cannot figure it out. How do I concatenate my variable properly?

Comment: I'd rather use sprintf or replacement tags for this, the concatenation you're doing in `$URL` variable is *waaaay* too messy.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: can you please tell me what is correct method I cannot find right way

Comment: Is the issue that the link doesn't resolve, that the `sortOrder` parameter has all the values, or that the `SECURITY-APPNAME` parameter and others have the wrong values?

Comment: See answer below. In the future please be sure to explain your issue in the question.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the actual issue. If that is incorrect please adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't concatenate in quotes. You can use curly braces so variable names are easier to see (and PHP knows where the variable ends).

```
$URL ="http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?siteid=0&SECURITY-APPNAME={$app_id}&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&keywords=";
```

or you can break the quotes and concatenate.

```
$URL ="http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?siteid=0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" . $app_id . "&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&keywords=";
```

Comment: I owe you big time! THANK YOU i didn't know about curly braces anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check each variable to confirm they have values or not and check it by concatenating them one after another them check...after that add next and check...you will be able to trace.

Comment: only $app_id is not working rest is fine